# Keycloak SAML adapter: how to export SP XML metadata?

Tags: metadata, saml-2.0, keycloak

After deploying [Keycloak 3.4 SAML adapter](http://www.keycloak.org/docs/3.4/securing_apps/index.html#_saml-general-config) (as tomcat valve for instance), I am looking for the proper way to get SP XML metadata file generated from certificate and services URL.

A question about [exporting Keycloak IdP XML metadata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33542812/keycloak-idp-saml-2-export-of-xml-metdata-to-an-sp) is answered but I found no equivalent for SP metadata.

Note: I am used to export such SP metadata from OIOSAML, Shibboleth and Spring Security SAML, and find it strange Keycloak does not document it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have your SP registered in a keycloak server instance there is an endpoint. See `org.keycloak.broker.saml.getSPDescriptor()`

I am afraid that there is no way of getting it directly from the SP. You always can use org.keycloak.saml.SPMetadataDescriptor.getSPDescriptor() as a helper for building it.

Me I end creating a template from another installation (WebLogic).

Hope it helps,

Luis

Answer (score 0):

In the client, choose the 'Installation' tab. At 'Format options' choose 'SAML Metadata SPSSODescriptor'.